# Not showing images in JToolBar

Tags: swing, netbeans, toolbar

```
    JButton btnCalendar = new JButton("Chart",new ImageIcon("new_chart.jpg"));
    btnCalendar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.getRootFrame(), "Chart clicked");
        }
    });
    jToolBar1.add(btnCalendar);
    jToolBar1.addSeparator();
```

I'm developing a Swing based application in which I want to add JToolBar with images in buttons.But images are not visible in the buttons

Comment: what changed, compared to your last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846883/jtoolbar-look-feel-in-swing

Comment: im not getting images in the button of tool bar.

Comment: doesn't answer my question: what _changed_ between the other and this? One implication being: don't start a second thread with the same question if you dont understand the answer to the first :-) Another: maybe it's only the image? check if it is where you expect it (f.i. by showing it on another button/label)

Comment: ya i checked to show the same image on a separate button. It's working but its not working in toolbar button.

Comment: still no answer to my question :-) Anyway, it's time for an sscce

Answer (score 0):

I face same problem and I resolved by 
use of following code :

```
ImageIcon newImage= new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("com/some/package/newItemImage.jpg"));
JButton newButton= new JButton(newImage);
this.add(newButton);
```